# Session object in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Does a Session object maintain the same TCP connection with a client?
In the code below, a request from the client is submitted to a handler, the handler creates a sessions object why does `session["count"]` on an object give a dictionary?
A response is then given back to the client, upon another request is the code re-executed?
So that another session object is created?
How does the session store the previous count information if it did not return a cookie to the client?

```
from appengine_utilities import sessions

class SubmitHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    session = sessions.Session()
    if "count" in session:
        session["count"]=session["count"]+1
    else:
        session["count"]=1

    template_values={'message':"You have clicked:"+str(session["count"])}
    # render the page using the template engine
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path,template_values))
```

Comment: Is my assumption that it's about Google App Engine correct?

Comment: Yes but it just uses the python sessions module

Comment: `appengine_utilities` is certainly not a standard Python module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made several questions so let's go one by one:

- Sessions are not related to TCP connections. A TCP connection is maintained when both client and server agreed upon that using the HTTP Header keep-alive. (Quoted from Pablo Santa Cruz in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519858/difference-between-session-http-connection)).
- Looking at the module [session.py](https://fossies.org/dox/gdata-2.0.18/apps_2marketplace__sample_2appengine__utilities_2sessions_8py_source.html) in line 1010 under `__getitem__` definition I've found the following `TODO: It's broke here, but I'm not sure why, it's returning a model object`. Could be something along these lines, I haven't debug it myself.
- From appengine_utilities [documentation](https://fossies.org/dox/gdata-2.0.18/classappengine__utilities_1_1sessions_1_1Session.html) sessions are stored in Datastore and Memcache or kept entirely as cookies. The first option also involves sending a token to the client to identify it in subsequent requests. Choosing one or another depends on your actual settings or the default ones if you haven't configured your own. [Default settings](https://fossies.org/dox/gdata-2.0.18/namespaceappengine__utilities_1_1settings__default.html#aa3014c2154997cef810fc9a2d5ba3ac7) are defined to use the Datastore option.
- About code re-execution you could check that yourself adding some logging code to count how many times is the function executed.

Something important, I have noticed that this library had it's [latest update](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client) on 2nd of January 2016, so it has gone unmaintained for 4 years. It would be best if you change to an up to date library, for example the [webapp2 session](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) module. Furthermore, [Python 2 is sunsetting](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) by this year (1st January 2020) so you might consider switching to python 3 instead.

PD: I found the exact code you posted under [this website](https://sites.google.com/site/usfcomputerscience/sessions). In case you took it from there consider next time to include a reference/citation to it's origin.