# mule 4 http listener - what is the use of ReadTimeout

Tags: mule, mule4, mule-esb

Using mule 4.4 community edition running on premise
while configuring HTTP listener came across this property :
[image]

Checked online and documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-documentation)

> Maximum time in milliseconds that the listener must wait while receiving a message.

I tried changing it to `5000` ( 5 seconds ) and was waiting without making a request for more than a minute .

Then I invoked the listener and it worked fine so I am confused on what is the significance of this attribute ?

when should we use this value ? os this meant to act as a response timeout which consumer of http listener would get ?

Thanks

Comment: Read Timeout
Number
Maximum time in milliseconds that the listener must wait while receiving a message.
30000

So that means once a TCP connection  is opened, till how long the listener should wait to get the body. From my understanding this is done sometimes by clients to keep the connection alive and to mitigate situations, where too many connections are opened and closed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763999/explain-http-keep-alive-mechanism

Comment: thanks @DheerajSharma , so  from my limited understanding this is something to do with  keeping ```sockets open``` ? does it mean largely in 99% of the times I will not need to worry about this property ? will I need to increase this value if the payload is really large ?

Comment: You can keep the default values in there and it won’t impact your implementation, given that you aren’t sending gb’s of data to your endpoints and not uploading any file using multi-part upload of HTML. And if you are then you’ll need to tweak it a bit according to your needs

Comment: Sure, will add it as an answer in sometime, well actually I’m in transit to work right now. Glad that i was of any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Read Timeout: (Number) Maximum time in milliseconds that the listener must wait while receiving a message. Default Value: 30000. [Documentation is here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-documentation)

Read Timeout indicates once a TCP connection is opened, till how long the listener should wait to get the body.
From my understanding this is done sometimes by clients to keep the connection alive and to mitigate situations, where too many connections are opened and closed. [Refer This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763999/explain-http-keep-alive-mechanism)

You can keep the default values in there and it won’t impact your implementation, given that you aren’t sending GB’s of data to your endpoints and not uploading any file using multi-part upload of HTML.

And if you are then you’ll need to tweak it a bit according to your needs